# Python Threading loop

Tags: python

I am have problem with this THREDING example. I have it working pretty good, but my problem is after it shows all 100 student threads. I am trying to put 20 random students in five different classes, but no matter what I do I can't seem to get the loop to work. If someone could please give me any direction on this, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
import random, time
from threading import Thread


class Students(Thread):
    ''' Represents a sleepy thread.'''


    def __init__(self, number, sleepMax):
        ''' Creates a thread with a given Name
        and a random sleep interval less than the maximum. '''
        Thread.__init__(self, name = "Student " + str(number))
        self._RequestInterval = random.randint(1, sleepMax)

    def run(self):
        '''Prints the thread's name and sleep interval and sleep
        for that interval. Print the name again at wake-up. '''
        count = 1
        course = 1
        print(" %s, Awaiting Request: %d seconds" % \
              ( self.getName(), self._RequestInterval))
        time.sleep(self._RequestInterval)
        if count == 20:
            print("%s Has A Spot Obtained in Class" % self.getName(), + course)
            print("Class", course, "has reached it limit!")
            count += 1
            course =+ 1
        else:
            #print("Class ", course, " is full.")
            print("%s Has A Spot Obtained in Class" % self.getName(), + course)



def main():
    ''' Creates the user's number of threads with sleep
    interval less than the user's maximum. Then start
    the threads'''

    NumberOfStudents = 100
    RequestTimer = 5    
    threadList = []
    for count2 in range(NumberOfStudents):
        threadList.append(Students(count2 + 1, RequestTimer))
    for thread in threadList: thread.start()



main()
```

I have even tried running my variable outside the class, but crashes.

Comment: What's the problem you have with the loop? It seems to run fine on my computer.

Comment: The problem is for every 20 random students it should print Class 1 has reached its limit, then the next 20 Class 2 had reach its limit, so on until it puts all 100 in classes

Comment: It keeps saying there all in class 1

Comment: Ah-ha, got it. Writing up an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with this.

1. The `count` and `course` variables are only in the `run` function, so they are local to that function only. This means that threads are not sharing this information. The solution: move them outside so that they are *class* variables (that is, they are now `Students.count` and `Students.course`).
2. Your print statements are a bit messed up. Using `print(a,b,c,...)` will print each of `a,b,c,...` on a separate line. The solution, enclose the thread's name and course number in a tuple and modify the format string slightly.
3. `course =+ 1` would've set `course` to `1` (because it's the same thing as `course = +1`) had that part of the if statement ever been executed (which it wasn't because of problem #1). Solution: flip the `=+` so that it's `course += 1`.
4. `count += 1` only happens when `count` is 20. You want this in the **else** part of the if statement. Also, in the **then** part, add the the line `count = 0` to reset the count.
5. Because these threads are running asynchronously, it can and does happen that `count` will go from 19 to 21 before you check `if count == 20`. Fixing this requires somewhat more advanced thread handling.

Below is the code with each of these problems fixed, except the last one (where I changed `count == 20` to `count >= 20` to at least show something interesting happen).

```
import random, time
from threading import Thread


class Students(Thread):
    ''' Represents a sleepy thread.'''
    count = 1
    course = 1

    def __init__(self, number, sleepMax):
        ''' Creates a thread with a given Name
        and a random sleep interval less than the maximum. '''
        Thread.__init__(self, name = "Student " + str(number))
        self._RequestInterval = random.randint(1, sleepMax)

    def run(self):
        '''Prints the thread's name and sleep interval and sleep
        for that interval. Print the name again at wake-up. '''
        print(" %s, Awaiting Request: %d seconds" % \
              ( self.getName(), self._RequestInterval))
        time.sleep(self._RequestInterval)
        if Students.count >= 20:
            print("%s Has A Spot Obtained in Class %s" % (self.getName(), Students.course))
            print("Class", Students.course, "has reached it limit!")
            Students.course += 1
            Students.count = 0
        else:
            #print("Class ", course, " is full.")
            print("%s Has A Spot Obtained in Class %s" % (self.getName(), Students.course))
            Students.count += 1



def main():
    ''' Creates the user's number of threads with sleep
    interval less than the user's maximum. Then start
    the threads'''

    NumberOfStudents = 100
    RequestTimer = 5    
    threadList = []
    for count2 in range(NumberOfStudents):
        threadList.append(Students(count2 + 1, RequestTimer))
    for thread in threadList: thread.start()



main()
```

Comment: Thank you, so much. It skips class 3 and goes to class 4 so it makes the last class 6

Comment: @MichaelSchultz: Yes, that's problem #5. You have (at least) two threads that went into the **then** part of the if conditional before either of them reset `Students.count` to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def run(self):
        '''Prints the thread's name and sleep interval and sleep
        for that interval. Print the name again at wake-up. '''
        count = 1
        course = 1
```

The variable `count` and `course` are both under the class instance, like you can think of there are 100 `count` variables and same to `course`

If you tried move the two outside the class, you should add a `gloabl` reference, like:

```
    def run(self):
        '''Prints the thread's name and sleep interval and sleep
        for that interval. Print the name again at wake-up. '''

        global count, course

        count = 1
        course = 1
```

this could be prevent crash, but not the result too. you can think of that there is only one `count` and `course`, but you have 100 threads running same time, maybe they are all use `count=1`, or some `count=1` some `count=2`...

So, we need to add the `Mutex` to the public variable (which we think its a resource, need to set mutex for threading safe).

The code:

```
import random, time, threading


count = 1
course = 1
mutex = threading.Lock()

class Students(threading.Thread):
    ''' Represents a sleepy thread.'''

    def __init__(self, number, sleepMax):
        ''' Creates a thread with a given Name
        and a random sleep interval less than the maximum. '''
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, name = "Student " + str(number))
        self._RequestInterval = random.randint(1, sleepMax)

    def run(self):
        '''Prints the thread's name and sleep interval and sleep
        for that interval. Print the name again at wake-up. '''

        global count, course

        print(" %s, Awaiting Request: %d seconds" % ( self.getName(), self._RequestInterval))
        time.sleep(self._RequestInterval)

        if mutex.acquire(1):

            print("%s Has A Spot Obtained in Class" % self.getName(), + course)

            if count == 20:
                count = 1
                course += 1
            else:
                count += 1

            mutex.release()


def main():
    ''' Creates the user's number of threads with sleep
    interval less than the user's maximum. Then start
    the threads'''

    NumberOfStudents = 100
    RequestTimer = 5
    threadList = []
    for count2 in range(NumberOfStudents):
        threadList.append(Students(count2 + 1, RequestTimer))
    for thread in threadList: thread.start()



main()
```